# how to make my Partial view page in asp mvc as a popup without using J-query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC project and want to create a modal popup on button click.
But without using J-query. Is this possible? if so give some suggestions guys
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778336/modal-dialog-without-jquery

Comment: Use can try bootstrap model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modal Dialog without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778336/modal-dialog-without-jquery)

Comment: You can use javascript

Comment: Thanks, @RaiVu but can't we call the partial view on Controller side and using CSS to make it as popup in middle of the page

Comment: Please have look this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380011/mvc-how-to-get-controller-to-render-partial-view-initiated-from-the-view

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap modal

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Show popup
</button>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       @Html.Partial("yourView")
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```